# How to add an JsonObject in a JsonArray at some random index

Tags: json

I am having a JsonAarray like below:

```
JsonARray ProfileTabs = [{"totalItemCount":0,"label":"Updates","name":"update"},{"totalItemCount":2,"label":"Members","url":"groups\/member\/list\/129","urlParams":[],"name":"members"},{"totalItemCount":5,"label":"Photos","url":"groups\/photo\/list","urlParams":{"group_id":129},"name":"photos"}]
```

As in the above JsonArray I am having 3 JsonObject at index 0, 1, 2.

Now I want to add a new JsonObject in this JsonArray at index 1.

So, I have created a new JsonObject as below:

```
JSONObject InfoTabJsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    InfoTabJsonObject.put("totalItemCount", 0);
                    InfoTabJsonObject.put("label", "Info");
                    InfoTabJsonObject.put("name", "info");
                    mProfileTabs.put(1, InfoTabJsonObject);
```

And added this JsonObject to the JsonArray at index 1, but after adding this JsonObject it replaces the original 1st index's JsonObject with the new one.

How can I achieve the index should remain properly, means that new one will be added to 1st index and the other one will adjust their index.

Please help me here, thanks in advanced.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I just came across the same problem and I was about to ask a question but I found your.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below code, uses `org.json.simple.JSONArray` and `org.json.simple.JSONObject`.

```
    JSONObject jsonObj1 = new JSONObject();
    jsonObj1.put("totalItemCount", 0);
    jsonObj1.put("label", "Updates");
    jsonObj1.put("name", "update");

    JSONObject jsonObj2 = new JSONObject();
    jsonObj2.put("totalItemCount", 2);
    jsonObj2.put("label", "Members");
    jsonObj2.put("url", "groups/member/list/129");
    JSONArray temp = new JSONArray();
    jsonObj2.put("urlParams", temp);
    jsonObj2.put("name", "members");

    JSONObject jsonObj3 = new JSONObject();
    jsonObj3.put("totalItemCount", 5);
    jsonObj3.put("label", "Photos");
    jsonObj3.put("url", "groups/photo/list");
    JSONObject temp1 = new JSONObject();
    temp1.put("group_id", 129);
    jsonObj3.put("urlParams", temp1);
    jsonObj3.put("name", "photos");

    JSONArray array=new JSONArray();
    array.add(jsonObj1); //adding objects into array 
    array.add(jsonObj2);
    array.add(jsonObj3);
    try {  

        // Writing to a file  
        System.out.println("Before addition of new object into array!");
        File file=new File("test1.json");  
        file.createNewFile();  
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);  
        fileWriter.write(array.toJSONString());  
        fileWriter.flush();  
        fileWriter.close();  

    } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }

    JSONObject InfoTabJsonObject = new JSONObject();
    InfoTabJsonObject.put("totalItemCount", 0); //adding objects into array
    InfoTabJsonObject.put("label", "Info");
    InfoTabJsonObject.put("name", "info");
    array.add(1, InfoTabJsonObject);
    System.out.println("After addition of new object into array!");
    try {  

        // Writing to a file  
        File file=new File("test.json");  
        file.createNewFile();  
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);  
        fileWriter.write(array.toJSONString());  
        fileWriter.flush();  
        fileWriter.close();  

    } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

**test1.json** The orginal one before adding new object in array.

```
[
{
    "name": "update",
    "label": "Updates",
    "totalItemCount": 0
},
{
    "urlParams": [],
    "name": "members",
    "label": "Members",
    "url": "groups\/member\/list\/129",
    "totalItemCount": 2
},
{
    "urlParams": {
        "group_id": 129
    },
    "name": "photos",
    "label": "Photos",
    "url": "groups\/photo\/list",
    "totalItemCount": 5
}
]
```

**test.json** The updated one after adding new object in array.

```
[
{
    "name": "update",
    "label": "Updates",
    "totalItemCount": 0
},
{
    "name": "info",
    "label": "Info",
    "totalItemCount": 0
},
{
    "urlParams": [],
    "name": "members",
    "label": "Members",
    "url": "groups\/member\/list\/129",
    "totalItemCount": 2
},
{
    "urlParams": {
        "group_id": 129
    },
    "name": "photos",
    "label": "Photos",
    "url": "groups\/photo\/list",
    "totalItemCount": 5
}
]
```